# Can I bypass TWRP asking for password to decrypt storage?

Tags: twrp, password, xiaomi

I have Xiaomi Redmi Note Plus. I wanted to install TWRP and root my device in order to flash mods. Well, the 1st time I enter TWRP after flashing it with adb, it demands the password. In steps, they mention that the password is the same as the one you had in the previous ROM. But actually, it didn't work.

Trying a different password/PIN without 0, still nothing, the problem that I lost all my data during the process.

So how can I disable or pass this password permanently to decrypt my storage and be able to flash mods?

Answer (score 1):

That TWRP requires a password is because your `/data` is encrypted, which is default since Android 6.

To permanently decrypt the filesystem, you need to **format `/data`** and flash a "disable force encryption" package. **Be aware that formatting `/data` will delete all your files, including photos, music, etc. in your internal storage**.

Also be careful when flashing other ROMs or applying OTAs, as most of them will make your `/data` encrypted again and you'll have to format it again. You need to flash the "force encryption disabler" every time you flash another ROM/OTA.